# What is the meaning of "at least within the last 2 years"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

If I want to specify in writing that I require some items from the last 2 years only and not from further back than 2 years, would it make sense to say:

> The items required need to be provided from at least the last 2 years.

Could the above be interpreted as "at least 2 years is the minimum requirement" but items from more than 2 years old are allowable?

Would it make more sense to say

> The items required need to be provided from at most the last 2 years?

Comment: I agree about *at most*, but I might put it as *item must have been received at most two years ago*. That is, the phrase *provided from* doesn't seem very clear to me. Or, *must have been received less than two years ago*.

Comment: The keywords *dated within* are all you need. Adding at most is overkill, and at least is the opposite.

Comment: _From no earlier than the last two years_, maybe?

Comment: I agree with @YosefBaskin . While not directly related to the question you asked, which is why this is a comment, I'd add that saying both "required" and "provided" is also "overkill." You would elicit the same response by simply saying, "The items *required* need to be from the last 2 years," or, "The items *provided* need to be from the last 2 years." Also, if by "last 2 years" you are referring to going back two years from present, saying "past" instead of "last" is somewhat clearer.

Comment: Are these items documents, with dates?

Comment: Brilliant everyone, thank you so much.

Comment: Yes Benjamin they are documents with dates

Comment: *"Examples need to be from within the past two years."* Absent additional context as to the topic, this would cover the ones I can think of.